# is it possible to print somther after calling return statement

Tags: python

im trying to print sometext after returning True like this:

```
if len(li) == sum(li):
    return True
    print("equality") 
else:
    return False
```

but in this code print is not working.

Comment: No you can't do that. Your options are print before the return, or print after you call the function.

Comment: Does my answer solves your question, if not please let me know else please accept it.

Comment: What difference would it make to print first?  You can always write `ret=…; print(…); return ret` so that no computation happens after the printing.

Answer (score 0):

return is a keyword. When a return statement is reached, Python will stop the execution of the current function, sending a value out to where the function was called

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. You can create a wrapper (this is usually done for logging) It will look something like this:

```
def equality_decorator(func): 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # calling the actual function now 
        # inside the wrapper function.
        result = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        if result:
            print("Equality")
        else:
            print('Inequality') 
        return result
    return wrapper


@equality_decorator
def your_actual_function(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Basically you wrap your function on another function, and inside this function you can add functionality, for example, printing something after execution. It is also used for timing function executions and printing them to console. I'll leave here a link if you want to dive deeper.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-wrappers-in-python/